# Log-likelihood function for Clayton copula

Tags: copula, likelihood

I am new to copula and I would like figure out how to find the log-likelihood function of Clayton copula and the expectation (log-likelihood function)? Any help please?

Comment: While I have no access to it right now, this [SAS help page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63939/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_copula_sect017.htm) points to Cherubini, U., Luciano, E., & Vecchiato, W. (2004). Chapter 7. In *Copula methods in finance*. John Wiley & Sons.

Comment: Thank you for the help page, yes they figure out the equation. That is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the density for the Clayton copula [in this document](https://www.nr.no/files/samba/bff/SAMBA2204b.pdf).
So, the log-likelihood, having observations $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ where $x_i = (u_i,v_i)$ is
$$\ell(\delta,x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log c(x_i, \delta).$$